# iOS apps for viewing generic map files

Tags: ios, software-recommendation, mapping

What are the iOS map-viewing apps that are compatible with the largest number of file formats for topographic maps and trail maps? (such as those found on the USGS website)

I'm really looking for a no-bells-and-whistles mapping "swiss army knife" app that's LOW on branding and not trying to sell me maps.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like [Maps n Trax](http://nixanz.com/maps-n-trax/) could help:

> With [it] you can view your own maps on your own iPhone instead of
>   just generic online maps or a limited selection of maps chosen by
>   somebody else. […] for specialist maps with details that are not
>   available on other mapping applications, such as highly detailed
>   topographic maps […].

From the description, this looks like something you could use. An [user guide](http://nixanz.com/maps-n-trax/user-guide/) can be found here. NB: im am not affiliated with them.